# How to create a Local DataBank inserting tables with form content by clicking on button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database, local-storage

I'm developing a webapp that works by inputs, where you place your enrollment and the program reports the loan. I placed the project in the cloud: https://repl.it/J4bL/4

So it happens that I have not put a database yet because I am still learning and I still have not found what I need.

The tutorials I saw teach communication with database and create a form only, then when you click the button it sends a form to the database, but when it clicks again it sends overwriting and I do not want this.

In short, I need to click on the button to send what was in the input (along with the number of the one that was borrowed -control 1 by ex-, date and time min sec -ddmmaaaa hhmmss example- of the click) to a database Local (bank that I also need to know what it should be - read a bit about sqlite but if you have better can talk -) through javascript and create a table in the database without replacing the previous one (you do not even have to create table since you play dice Without, replace the previous data) and after sending the data clear the input so that the data of the person is not visible.

Summarize to clarify the questions, and so that the question is not reported:

Has a text input and a button

__________________ [borrow]

The person types the license plate and clicks on lend

12345567890000** [borrow]**

Through JS the button sends what was in the input (along with date and time) to a local database

**Local database** *
Which to use ?;
Local Bank - data needs to be stored in the machine*

**Javascript**

How to send the data How to create a new table when sending (not replace what already had); How to delete what was in the input so as not to leave the data visible.

**Clean form**

____________________ [return]

*Lend / Return function already exists on onclick*

**Information saved on the Bank**

Control 1 | Loaned | ddmmaa hhmmss | 12345567890000

**Click again**

Control 1 | Loaned | ddmmaa hhmmss | 12345567890000

Control 1 | Returned | ddmmaa hhmmss | 12345567890000

================================

ALL THE OPEN AND TESTABLE CODE IS ONLINE ON THE LINK BELOW

Https://repl.it/J4bL/4

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Please simplify

Comment: What is the best local database to use and how every time I click a button the javascript saves the input text on the data bank